# How to calculate the new position at time $t$ of celestial bodies with variable acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, computational-physics, celestial-mechanics

## Intro

For an $N$-body simulation of celestial bodies I need to calculate

- on the one hand the accelerations of the celestial bodies based on the received gravitational forces [done]
- and  on the other hand the new position of the individual calestial body a time $t$. **[todo]**.

## Problem

How do I calculate the new position at time $t$ of a body with a constantly changing acceleration?

## Some additional information

- The acceleration is computed in step one for all bodies in the system and after calcualting the new position, then it starts from the beginning with the new calculated position and velocity from step 2.
- For each body I know the mass, the start and current position (from step 2), the initial and current velocity (from step 2), the acceleration (from step 1).

### What I have did so far

- I calculated the current accelerations for each body based on the received gravitational forces.
- I calculated the new position and velocity based of an constant acceleration which is obivsoulsy wrong, because in each iteration the distance between the bodies changes and therefore the received force which results in a new acceleration.

PS:
I would be happy about a formula instead of abstract equations that I have to derive a few times myself. Not having a strong mathematical background, the latter would keep me busy for a while.

Comment: This isn't an easy problem. You might to google for "n body simulation" (with or without quotes) to see how other people do it. The most direct way is to use a very small time step (so positions don't change that much), but more efficient methods exist.

Comment: You might check out Runge-Kutta methods: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods   I made a visualization of one of the graphs in that page that I found useful: https://observablehq.com/@pcarleton/runge-kutta-visualized  For n-body, you would calculate each 'k' (k1, k2, k3, k4) based on the intermediate positions of the other bodies

Comment: You have to look into "integrators". The simplest possible integrator is the Euler method which is basically just `v+=a*dt; x+=v*dt`. The Euler method is very bad though. For accuracy the Runge-Kutta method works very well. Symplectic integrators are great for physics problems because they conserve energy (at least better than other methods). The Verlet method is simple and works well.

Comment: I advise you to first implement the Euler method to get something working and to iron out any bugs and when that is working correctly you can implement one of the better integrators

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion you are right, the v+=a*dt; x+=v*dt does the job at the moment. Thanks for mentioning the others.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion To be sure, can you tell me what delta t (dt) is exactly? Is it the difference between the current time (ti) and the initial time (t0) or the difference between the current time (ti) and the last point in time of the calculation (ti-1)?

Comment: @Dawid It is the timestep, so the difference between current time and last point time of the calculation. The smaller the timestep, the more accurate. A timestep of $dt=0.1$ should give you at least decent results but smaller is better. But on the flipside the simulation will run slower